# How to I turn a column of lists into a set with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, set

I have a dataframe below with the column 'samples' that contains lists for each row.  I want to turn these into a set.  My expected output would be each row in the 'samples' column to not contain any duplicates since it was turned into a set.  Any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'trial_num': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
     'subject': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
     'samples': [list(np.random.randn(3).round(2)) for i in range(6)]
    }
)
```

Output expected is below:

```
   trial_num  subject               samples
0          1        1   {0.75, 0.87, -0.54}
1          2        1   {-0.67, 1.5, -0.46}
2          3        1  {0.13, -0.56, -0.11}
3          1        2   {-0.78, 0.48, 1.03}
4          2        2   {0.13, 0.62, -0.14}
5          3        2   {0.61, -0.59, 0.43}
```

Comment: `df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.samples.tolist(),index=df.index))
` this is convert to dataframe , `df['samples'] = df['samples'].map(set)`, this is to set

Comment: Could you provide a small expected output? There are multiple ways as WeNYoBen and Quang described. Which output are you expecting?

Comment: df['samples'] = df['samples'].map(set) is what I needed.  Thanks, guys!  Added the expected output.

Comment: @WeNYoBen is there a way to avoid {set} being put in the samples column where it is blank?

Comment: @acodejdatam I have adding the solution , using np,where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
df['New']=np.where(df.samples=='','',df.samples.map(set))
df
Out[312]: 
   trial_num  subject               samples                   New
0          1        1   [-0.96, -0.3, 1.03]   {-0.96, 1.03, -0.3}
1          2        1   [1.24, -0.04, 0.33]   {-0.04, 1.24, 0.33}
2          3        1                                            
3          1        2    [-0.46, 0.1, 1.34]    {-0.46, 1.34, 0.1}
4          2        2   [-0.8, -0.63, 0.16]   {-0.8, -0.63, 0.16}
5          3        2  [0.88, -0.27, -0.72]  {0.88, -0.27, -0.72}
```